# OLS regression in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, regression

so far i used following code for regressions in my data

```
for ii = 1:size(dependent,2) % Loop through columns
Regressors(:,ii) = regstats(dependent(:,ii),independent:,ii),'linear',{'beta','tstat','adjrsquare'}); % Calculate regression
```

My question is if I can do a OLS regression as well.
I found the mvnrmle function but don't know how to use in the same context as above.

Thank you!

Comment: Two questions: 1.) Do you have access to that function (it's part of the Financial Toolbox)? 2.) Have you looked at [the `mvnrmle` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/mvnrmle.html) - that should explain how to use the function.

Comment: `regstats` does do OLS regression...

Comment: 1. Yes I do. 2. I also did that. However I'm very new to Matlab (less than a week of use) and dont really udnerstand whats going on. Also I will havae a look at regstats